# How to access WAMP server from non-localhost address?

Tags: php, apache, wamp

We have looked up about 20 different questions like this one and none of them have worked for us. We are attempting to access our WAMP server from something other than localhost. localhost works fine, but 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.17 (our internal ip address), and the external ip address cannot access the server. The server is clearly up because we are getting a "403 forbidden" error and can access using "localhost", but nothing else. We obviously have it to "put online", and we have tried so many edits of the httpd.conf file. We are running apache2.4.9. I found there is an update in that version and the syntax is different but was unsure of which files to edit with that syntax because we also were told to edit the phpmyadmin.conf, sqlbuddy.conf, and webgrind.conf files.  Here is the httpd.conf as of now. It's probably wrong, but like I said we have tried so many varieties that it's getting hazy. Any help is appreciated.

httpd.conf:

```
 <Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
     #
     # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
     # or any combination of:
     #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
     #
     # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
     # doesn't give it to you.
     #
     # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
     # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
     # for more information.
     #
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
     # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
     #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
     #
     AllowOverride all
     #
     # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
     #

     #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Require local
     Require ip 192.168.1

</Directory>
```

Edit: This is the listen directory,

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

Edit2: Also have change this snippet

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Require local
     Require ip 192.168.1
```

to this (still not accessible):

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Require all granted
```

Comment: `Require local` This is making it so that you are only allowing the machine that is hosting the server to have access to the pages, where everyone else gets a 403.

Comment: And `Require ip 192.168.1` will only allow the client with 192.168.1 access.

Comment: Ok so I just commented out the Require local line and I still was unable to access it from both internal and loopback. I took it on, and offline a few times and restarted the services a few times after saving the config file. Is there anything special I need to do in terms of reloading or something?

Comment: What's your `Listen` directive?

Comment: We also have tried turning off the firewall and creating a rule to allow port 80 traffic through. Still could not access from anything other than the localhost.